# 3D cube Animation for view by swift

Tags: ios, swift, cube

I want 3d cube for 3 or 4 view (UIViewController) by using swift. I follow this website [Link](https://maniacdev.com/2013/11/library-allowing-you-to-easily-set-up-view-navigation-with-3d-cube-transitions).
My code is bellow. I want 3d cube view when I will do selected only 3 view. But my project are doing all view 3d. How can stopped all page 3d cube.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CubeControllerDataSource {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let cubeVC : CubeController = CubeController()
    cubeVC.dataSource = self
    cubeVC.wrapEnabled = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = cubeVC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func numberOfViewControllersInCubeController(cubeController: CubeController!) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func cubeController(cubeController: CubeController!, viewControllerAtIndex index: Int) -> UIViewController! {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    switch (index % 3){
        case 0:
            return storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC1")
        case 1:
            return storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC2")
        case 2:
            return storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC3")
        default:
            return nil
    }
}
```